# Not receiving emails from phpmailer and cpanel

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, cpanel

So I have a contact form that uses phpmailer. It sends an email from one Gmail account to another. But I can't seem to get the receiving email to receive any emails.

The script is hosted on a cpanel (RivalHost) and the domain is on GoDaddy. I asked RivalHost if they were blocking SMTP connections or blocking ports 587 or 465, and they said they weren't. So I have no idea what's causing the issue. The script works perfectly fine on my localhost, just not on cpanel

Heres the mailing script:

```
<?php

$result="";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port=465;
    $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
    $mail->SMPTSecure='ssl';
    $mail->Username='sendingemail@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password='*********';

    $mail->setFrom('sendingemail@gmail.com');
    $mail->addAddress('receivingemail@gmail.com');
    $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject='Contact: '.$_POST['subject'];
    $mail->Body='Message: '.$_POST['msg'].'</h1>';

    if(!$mail->send()){
        $result='something went wrong';
        echo $result;


    } else {
        $result="thank you";
        echo $result;
    }
}
```

?>

I was also told to check my MX records, but wasn't really sure what to change them to, or if I needed to change them at all:

```
MX  0   ********.com    3599    RBL
```

Comment: Set `SMTPDebug = 2` and look at the debug output. That will confirm that your message is being sent. If it is, check your spam folder. Also, you’re using an old version of PHPMailer, so upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
PHPMailer uses exeptions. You can put your code in try/catch block to get exceptions caused emails not to be sent.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //defaults to using php "mail()"; the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

try {
  //Email information comes here
  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
}
```

**Solotion 2:**
Are you also using the CSF firewall? If so, check to see if the "SMTP_BLOCK" setting is enabled. If STMP_BLOCK is enable contact to hosting to disable it.

Comment: Added your code, didn't return any errors. it returned Message sent ok, but still no email received

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your settings:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message sent!';
}
```